# Is the AESCryptoServiceProvider available in embargoed countries

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

If I try and use the AESCryptoServiceProvider from a country facing strong encryption export restrictions what will happen?

Will it work?

Will I get a PlatformNotSupportedException?

Comment: Is there someone actually in one of these countries with a legal version of windows that can try this?

Comment: Which countries, and whose laws are you trying to comply with?

Comment: I didn't ask about complying with laws, If I try and use AES encryption built into dotnet, in a country like Iran should I expect it to work, and if not how will if fail (I need to detect it). I would like to leave aside the issue of weather or not using an encryption module but not shipping one is legal. That is a question for lawyers, as a developer I want to know what happens if I try.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Since Iran probably cannot legally obtain any version of Microsoft windows, there is no reason to expect the versions you find there to have any particular restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

It will work.

There is nothing in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) that suggests otherwise.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation states that it would either.

Comment: @trampster - and yet, this is definitely something that would have been documented. And since the framework can be legally installed on computers around the globe, I am sure MS have cleared the use of the provider already. Otherwise, wouldn't they be in violation of export restrictions?

Comment: Are you sure that windows in embargoed countries contains the rsaenh.dll module required to run this provider

Comment: @trampster - AES 128bit is not under export restrictions. AES 256 is.

Comment: @Oded can you provide a link for that

Comment: You need to be more precise about "emabargoed" countries, but for example almost all transactions to Iran, Cuba, and Syria require a State Department license. That includes Microsoft operating systems irrespective of any crypto in them, and probably includes anything the OP is contemplating doing (or has already done). But those are US laws, your country may be different.

Comment: @trampster - Apologies, I misinterpreted something I read (regarding 128bit not being restricted). However, the restrictions would be those that were imposed on Microsoft, not you (since they are the ones distributing the dll and .NET). Since the DLL in question is needed for things like VPN access to work on windows, I would say that if it is a windows machine, the DLL will be present and you can use AES encryption.